Where does the (x-a) come from in the Taylor series?
I have recently been learning about the Taylor series in Maths class. I understand how the formula is derived except for the (x-a) part. Everyone (meaning my teacher and people on youtube) seem to just add it into the formula with no reason. Here is a link to a youtube video made by Tom Rocks Maths:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DULzJmUHN5g&t=1316s
If you skip to 1:00, you will see that when writing out the polynomial, he writes out (x-a) with no explanation! I cannot figure out why he has used (x-a) instead of x. This is not supposed to be criticising his videos, I think I am just missing something obvious here...

Did you derive the formula centered in $0$, so $a=0$?

The idea is that you know a lot about the function at the point $x=a$ and you hope to use that information to evaluate $f(x)$ when $x$ is near $a$ (so that $|x-a|$ is small).

It might help, and in this I'm thinking about what might have been something you dealt with in a precalculus course and thus something you may have recently worked with and thus remember (assuming you've very recently taken/studied precalculus topics), to recall that replacing $x$ with $x-a$ in a formula for a function translates the graph of the function $a$ units to the right. Thus, using $(x-a)$ in a Taylor series shifts its graph to the right by $a$ units from where it would have been when using powers of $x.$ This observation, ALONG with what others have said, might help.

It also might help to recall the formula for the linearization of a function at a point: $f(a) + f'(a)(x-a)$ (see here). Even better, especially if you also covered it (if not, it still might be in your text), is the quadratic approximation of a function at a point.

A Taylor series has the form
$$T_af(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \frac12 f''(a)(x-a)^2+\dotsb.$$
The constant part $f(a)$ makes sure that the value of the series at $a$ is the correct one. The linear term $f'(a)(x-a)$ has the purpose of producing the right first derivative. It should not, however, disturb the value at $a$. We need a linear function with slope $f'(a)$ and a zero at $a$ to make this work. Simply taking $f'(a)x$ is not the right choice, because now the partial sum $f(a) + f'(a)x$ does not have the right value at $x = a$. It evaluates as $f(a) + f'(a)a$ when we actually want $f(a)$. Taking $f'(a)(x-a)$ fixes the problem as this function is obviously zero at $x = a$.
The same applies to all higher terms. Next we need a quadratic function such that at $x = a$, the second derivative is $f''(a)$ while the function itself and its first derivative are zero. Otherwise we are destroying everything we have worked for when we constructed the earlier terms. The only function to do this is $\frac12 f''(a)(x-a)^2$.
In general, the term $g_n$ of degree $n$ in the Taylor series is supposed to have $g_n^{(i)}(a) = 0$ for $i < n$ and $g_n^{(n)}(a) = f^{(n)}(a)$. There is only one polynomial of degree at most $n$ with these properties: It has an $n$-fold root at $x = a$, so it is a multiple of $(x-a)^n$. In order to stay with degree at most $n$, we may only multiply with a constant. Since the $n$-th derivative of $(x-a)^n$ at $x = a$ is $n!$, multiply by $\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}$ to get the correct one.
TLDR: The partial sum up to term $n-1$ already give the correct derivatives up to the $n-1$-st. Taking a multiple of $x^n$ destroys this fact, while $(x-a)^n$ doesn't.
